# ReportViewer Not Displaying Report - URL Issue?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have this:

```
<Window>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Viewer}" />
</Window>
internal class MainViewModel : ObservableObject{

        private WindowsFormsHost _viewer;
        public WindowsFormsHost Viewer
        {
            get { return _viewer; }
            set { Set(() => Viewer, ref _viewer, value); }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _viewer = new WindowsFormsHost();
            var reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://someservername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx");                    
            reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "ItemPath=/somefolder1/somefolder2/ReportX";
            Viewer.Child = reportViewer;
        }
    }
```

I can see a disabled reporting services tool bar across the top of the window but no report. I've played around assigning various string to ReportPath and ReportServerUrl but nothing. Is this a URL issue? Of course the URL works if I put it into a browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same issue. I am not sure if this work for you but in my case,
The line in your code `Var reportViewer = new ReportViewer` must be moved to xaml for example

```
                <WindowsFormsHost DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White">
                <rv:ReportViewer
                    x:Name="_ReportViewer"  
                    ReportRefresh="CreateStatement" 
                    BackColor="White"  
                    BorderStyle="None"
                    ></rv:ReportViewer>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
```

now,why it behaves like this I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a really old question, but more looking for the future people who find the same error and I just find and solved the same error...

You need to introduce the function call RefreshReport of the reportViewer class. Like this:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _viewer = new WindowsFormsHost();
        var reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://someservername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx");                    
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "ItemPath=/somefolder1/somefolder2/ReportX";
        reportviewer.RefreshReport();
        Viewer.Child = reportViewer;
    }
```